# detected potential leak by analyze

Tags: ios, memory-leaks

the following is my code:

```
    UIImage *takePhotoImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"add_pic.png"];
    self.takePhoto = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120, 100, takePhotoImg.size.width, takePhotoImg.size.height)];
    [_takePhoto setImage:takePhotoImg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_takePhoto addTarget:self action:@selector(takePhotoBtn) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:_takePhoto];
```

when I use analyze,it shows the line:

```
[_takePhoto setImage:takePhotoImg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Potential leak of an object allocated.
Did I need add release,or just ignore?
thank you in advance

UPDATE:
I did have released the button _takePhoto in my dealloc:

```
-(void)dealloc
{
    [_takePhoto release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

my property :

```
@property(nonatomic,retain)UIButton *takePhoto;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not using ARC then yes, you need to release it. When you add it to `self.view`'s subview, `self.view` will retain it so the button will not go away.

If you don't need to access the button and don't need to hold a reference, you can release it right after the `addSubview:` call.

However, it looks like `takePhoto` is a property on your class. If that's the case and you want to hold a reference to the button for later use, just add the `[_takePhoto release]` call to your class `dealloc` method. That should surpress the code analysis warning.

Comment: In that case, try using `_takePhoto` rather than `self.takePhoto` on line 2 of your sample. I believe using `self.takePhoto` will effectively "double retain" (since the property has the `retain` characteristic), which isn't what you want.

Answer (score 0):

change code:

```
    self.takePhoto = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120, 100,      takePhotoImg.size.width, takePhotoImg.size.height)];
```

to

```
    self.takePhoto = [[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120, 100, takePhotoImg.size.width, takePhotoImg.size.height)] autorelease];
```

[_takePhoto release] in delloc method is for the retain in setter method. Every time you call self.takePhoto = aNewTakePhote, aNewTakePhote will be retained once.